# how to get record from store selecting row in grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

in extjs 3 I use:

```
    if (Model1.getSelectionModel().getSelections().length == 1 ) {
    record = Model1.store.getAt(Model1.getStore().indexOf(Model1.getSelectionModel().getSelected()))
 }
```

, but in extjs4 it's not work ...

Comment: which part does not work? the if statement or the getAt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `getSelections()` method in ExtJS4. You need to use the `getSelection()`.

In previous versions you had:

1. getSelection() -> Used to get the first selected record.
2. getSelections() -> Used to the selected records.

In ExtJS4, you have only `getSelection()` which returns an array of the currently selected records. So you need to change your if statement. That should fix your problem.

**extra note:**
 Use the `getStore()` method to access the store rather than using the property name `store`.